# Getting First and Last Points in a Series in an SQL table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

OK...

I have a table (in BigQuery) that has:

journey_id
timestamp
latitude
longitude

What I would like to do is to convert this into a table that has:

journey_id
start_timestamp
end_timestamp
start_latitude
start_longitude
end_latitude
end_longitude

Now: I can easily do this programmatically: i.e., I take a list of DISTINCT journey_ids, and then iterate over them, grabbing the lat, long at the minimum timestamp, and at the maximum.

But I'm fairly sure that that is an incredibly inefficient way to do this, that will take 500x as long (and cost 5,000x as much) as a single SQL query.

Could anyone give me any pointers as to how I might achieve this?

Thanks
Robert

Answer (score 1):

The SQL query you need should

1. group by journey_id
2. select min / max timestamp - these are obviously start and end time
3. select latitude / longitude at these timestamps. There are many ways to do it, the way I would use here is `array_agg( ... order by ... limit 1)[offset(0)]` - this aggregates all values in the group, sorting them by another column, keeping only first item - i.e. at minimum or maximum timestamp.

It should be something like

```sql
select 
  journey_id, 
  min(timestamp) as start_timestamp,
  array_agg(latitude order by timestamp limit 1)[offset(0)] as start_latitude,
  max(timestamp) as end_timestamp,
  array_agg(latitude order by timestamp desc limit 1)[offset(0)] as end_latitude
from table
group by journey_id
```